# Error Trapping and Logic in R

Tags: r, input

```
PresentValue <- function(interest.rate, number.periods, frequency) {

    if (interest.rate > 1) {interest.rate = interest.rate/100} else {"input interest.rate as a    whole number"}
    if (frequency < 1 || frequency > 12 ) {"frequency must be between 1 and 12"} else {interest.rate = interest.rate/frequency}

    (1+interest.rate)^number.periods  
}
```

The code above is simple but I need to catch user input error. I looked at `tryCatch` but it made no sense to me.  Plus I think that it is not what I need at this point.

Basically, I need to do the following things

First, make sure the user has input the interest rate as a whole number (i.e. 5% not .05)
Second I need "ask" user how the rate is paid (frequency) monthly, annually, etc.  Then divide the interest rate by the frequency.

What is strange is that the first condition only checks when the other if statements are remarked out.

This function will be an object in a larger set of functions so I think I need to consider these as warnings that will ultimately work with try catch.  Finally, it would be nice if on the interest rate error the function did not terminate but simply asked for the user to correctly input the interest rate.

In apologize for the simplicity in advance but just could not find what I was looking for.

#### EDIT add some conetxt

Below is the bigger function. This shows the table output for convexity I need to incorporate duration and then a yield and price table and output to a page using swerve. This is going into a text book on structured finance. So it needs to work well for students

```
Bond.Cash.Flow <-function(issue.date, start.date, end.date, coupon, principal, 
frequency,  price){

library(lubridate)
  issue.date <- as.Date(c(issue.date), "%m-%d-%Y")
  start.date <- as.Date(c(start.date), "%m-%d-%Y")
  end.date <- as.Date(c(end.date), "%m-%d-%Y")
  price = price/100


  # 30/360 day count calculation 
    d1 = day(issue.date)
    m1 = month(issue.date)
    y1 = year(issue.date)
    d2 = day(end.date)
    m2 = month(end.date)
    y2 = year(end.date)


 diff = (max(0, 30 - d1) + min(30, d2) + 360*(y2-y1) + 30*(m2-m1-1))/360
 ncashflows = diff * frequency
 cf.period = seq(1:ncashflows)
 pmtdate = seq(start.date, end.date, by = "6 months")

time.period = (cf.period * 6)/12

 couponincome = rep(coupon/frequency * principal, ncashflows)
 principalincome = rep(0,ncashflows)
 principalincome[ncashflows] = principal
cashflow = couponincome + principalincome


  # Yield to maturity
     irr <- function(rate, time.period, cashflow, principal, price){
      pv = cashflow * 1/(1+rate)^time.period
      proceeds = principal * price
      sum(pv) - proceeds
  }

ytm = uniroot(irr, interval = c(lower = -.20, upper = .20), tol =.000000001, 
time.period = time.period, cashflow = cashflow, principal = principal, price = price)$root

 ytm.vec = c(rep(ytm,ncashflows))
 pv.factor = 1/(1+ytm.vec)^time.period
 pv.cashflow = cashflow*pv.factor
 pv.price = pv.cashflow /(principal * (price/100))
 pv.period = pv.price * time.period
 cvx.time = time.period*(time.period + 1)
 cf.cvx = (cashflow/(1+ytm)^(time.period + 2))/(principal * (price/100))
 cf.cvx.period = cf.cvx * cvx.time

cashflow.table <- data.frame(Period = cf.period, Time = time.period, 
Cashflow = cashflow,  PVFactor = pv.factor,PV = pv.cashflow, PV.Price = pv.price, 
pv.period = pv.period, cvx.time = cvx.time, cf.cvx = cf.cvx, 
cf.cvx.period = cf.cvx.period)


cashflow.table
(sum(pv.period) / (price * 100))/( 1+ (ytm/frequency))
.5 * ((sum(cf.cvx.period)/(price * 100)))
print(xtable(cashflow.table, digits = 4))
}
```

---

```
Bond.Cash.Flow <-function(issue.date, start.date, end.date, coupon, principal, 
frequency,  price){

library(lubridate)
  issue.date <- as.Date(c(issue.date), "%m-%d-%Y")
  start.date <- as.Date(c(start.date), "%m-%d-%Y")
  end.date <- as.Date(c(end.date), "%m-%d-%Y")
  price = price/100
```

# 30/360 day count calculation 
    d1 = day(issue.date)
    m1 = month(issue.date)
    y1 = year(issue.date)
    d2 = day(end.date)
    m2 = month(end.date)
    y2 = year(end.date)

```
 diff = (max(0, 30 - d1) + min(30, d2) + 360*(y2-y1) + 30*(m2-m1-1))/360
 ncashflows = diff * frequency
 cf.period = seq(1:ncashflows)
 pmtdate = seq(start.date, end.date, by = "6 months")

time.period = (cf.period * 6)/12

 couponincome = rep(coupon/frequency * principal, ncashflows)
 principalincome = rep(0,ncashflows)
 principalincome[ncashflows] = principal
cashflow = couponincome + principalincome
```

# Yield to maturity
     irr <- function(rate, time.period, cashflow, principal, price){
      pv = cashflow * 1/(1+rate)^time.period
      proceeds = principal * price
      sum(pv) - proceeds
  }

```
ytm = uniroot(irr, interval = c(lower = -.20, upper = .20), tol =.000000001, 
time.period = time.period, cashflow = cashflow, principal = principal, price = price)$root

 ytm.vec = c(rep(ytm,ncashflows))
 pv.factor = 1/(1+ytm.vec)^time.period
 pv.cashflow = cashflow*pv.factor
 pv.price = pv.cashflow /(principal * (price/100))
 pv.period = pv.price * time.period
 cvx.time = time.period*(time.period + 1)
 cf.cvx = (cashflow/(1+ytm)^(time.period + 2))/(principal * (price/100))
 cf.cvx.period = cf.cvx * cvx.time

cashflow.table <- data.frame(Period = cf.period, Time = time.period, 
Cashflow = cashflow,  PVFactor = pv.factor,PV = pv.cashflow, PV.Price = pv.price, 
pv.period = pv.period, cvx.time = cvx.time, cf.cvx = cf.cvx, 
cf.cvx.period = cf.cvx.period)


cashflow.table
(sum(pv.period) / (price * 100))/( 1+ (ytm/frequency))
.5 * ((sum(cf.cvx.period)/(price * 100)))
print(xtable(cashflow.table, digits = 4))
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "consider these as warnings that will ultimately work with try catch"? do you want to catch a warning?

Comment: Hopefully @agstudy will undelete their answer below, since I believe all you're really looking for is `stop`, which is discussed in their answer.

Comment: Hmm...now I see why agstudy deleted their answer. You need to clarify things as requested above. You specify a fair number of divergent requirements, each of which would require a very different sort of solution.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what do you want to do since you don't give a precise context of the call of your function. So my answer will be partial.

1. Please assign default values to your arguments, especially one you have more than one argument to validate. Default arguments uses **lazy evaluation** in R and are really a powerful feature of the language.
2. Use `stop` and/or `warning` to throw an error/warning and catch it in its final call context to give the user a human message.
3. take a look at `match.call`(difficult for a beginner) to get the effective call of your function.

here an example using `stop`:

```
PresentValue <- function(interest.rate, number.periods=1, frequency=1) {
if (missing(interest.rate))
  stop("Need to specify interest.rate as number between 0 and 1 for calculations.")
if (!is.numeric(interest.rate)  )
  stop("No numeric  interest.rate specified.")
if (interest.rate <0 | interest.rate > 1)
  stop("No valid  interest.rate specified.")
 ## you do the same thing for other arguments

}
```

some tests:

```
PresentValue()
Error in PresentValue() : 
  Need to specify interest.rate as number between 0 and 1 for calculations.
> PresentValue("a")
Error in PresentValue("a") : No numeric  interest.rate specified.
> PresentValue(5)
Error in PresentValue(5) : No valid  interest.rate specified.
> PresentValue(0.9)  ## normal use
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, to answer your question.  I have R code written that can solve for the yield of a bond given a price, generate a table of cash flows, compute duration, convexity.  The function will call this function. I think to use try catch these functions must pass warnings.

Comment: @GlennSchultz do you mean that you have something like `f(price){...; compte interset_rate; call(PresentValue(interset_rate)`;...}` Maybe it is better to add some pseudo code to your question.

Comment: I tried to post the code here but it is too long by 1,494 characters. Is there a way to post it without a question?

Comment: Below is the bigger function. This shows the table output for convexity I need to incorporate duration and then a yield and price table and output to a page using swerve.  This is going into a text book on structured finance.  So it needs to work well for students